# Can I create event attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Can I create my own attributes on HTML elements that are treated as JavaScript code, and able to be executed when my code so desires?

For example, say I want to create a custom event `onpagerefresh`, and at the same time, allow the person who writes the HTML to add attributes that handle this event.

```
<body onpagerefresh="updateContents()">
```

I am able to parse the HTML to get the value of this new `onpagerefresh` attribute, but how do I tell JavaScript to treat anything in this attribute as JavaScript code rather than a string?

Comment: And the first person who says _"Use eval()"_ will be slapped.

Comment: Why would they be slapped? If you have a string, and you want to treat it as JavaScript code, `eval()` or one of its friends is the perfect tool. If you were only ever calling functions, you could do `window[fnName]()`.

Comment: @alex If you feel like `eval()` is _really_ the right thing to be using in this case, then please, add that as an answer with reasoning as to why it's a good idea in this instance.

Comment: `eval()` isn't *always* evil.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Function()`, the [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), to get a function object from your string and then assign it to an attribute of your object. Ex:

```
var divElement = document.getElementById('mydiv');
divElement.onpagerefresh = new Function("èvent", "alert();");
```

Whether that's better than eval() in any meaningful way is debatable (though it does give you a distinct scope), but that would be how you do it. Possibly a better option in your case would be to allow the person implementing the HTML to use a preexisting function name (`onpagerefresh="updateContents"`) and then simply execute that one as e.g. `window["updateContents"]()`. That way you don't let any old DOM insertion write random javascript into your code. But of course that limits the functionality.

Comment: `new Function()` is exactly what I'm looking for, as it allows you to pass in the `event` parameter available on all "vanilla" DOM Events.

Comment: But I think you have a typo in your code. `e` should be a string, (and ideally named `event` to match the other DOM events): `new Function("event", "alert();");`

Comment: And second, setting the `onpagerefresh` property is not the same thing as "assigning it to an attribute".

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create an actual event accompanied with support for listeners, this Mozilla article describes a way to do so:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

In your case:

```
var event = new Event('onpagerefresh');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('onpagerefresh', function (e) {
    updateContents();
}, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Though, be wary of cross-browser support.

Comment: Regarding cross-browser support, all browsers which have `addEventListener()` should have `dispatchEvent()`, right?

Comment: That is correct. IE 8 and below are special and I believe will need attachEvent() and fireEvent()